# $f(x) = \int_0^x g(t)dt$ and $g(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$. Is $f(x)$ differentiable on $(-\infty , 0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

$f(x) = \int_0^x g(t)dt$ and $g(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

By using first fundamental theorem of calculus, we can say $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[0 , \infty)$.
Can we say anything about differentiability of $f(x)$ when $x$ is negative?

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: What do you think the answer will be?

Comment: $\int_0^{x}=-\int_{x}^0$

Answer (score 1):

In $f(x) = \int_0^x g(t)dt$ , we can substitute $T=-t$ to get :
$f(x) = \int_0^{-x} -g(-T)dT$

$f(x) = -\int_0^{-x} g(-T)dT$

Now , we try to get $f(-x)$ :

$f(-x) = -\int_0^{-(-x)} g(-T)dT$
$-f(-x) = \int_0^{x} g(-T)dT$

Given that $g(t)$ is continuous in R , we know that $g(-x)$ is continuous in R too.

Hence , $-f(-x)$ is Differentiable in the given range which is having constant $(-1)$ multiplier & $X=-x$ :
In other words : $f(X)$ is Differentiable in the given negative range.